# fade function trouble

Tags: javascript, events, dom

I made a script that fades out a button when the mouse goes over it and fades in on mouse out. It works fine on the 'mouseover' event, but it fails on the 'mouseout' any ideas?

P.S. I not using jquery because I am trying to learn this for educational purposes.

Go here to see the code: http://jsfiddle.net/assuredlonewolf/t2sYX/
Feel free to edit it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got two issues:

- The interval is created multiple times, and cleared nowhere
- You're using `< 1.1` to determine whether the element should become visible or not, while the `fade` count start at 1.1. Clearly, 1.1 is never lower than 1.1.

[Updated code](http://jsfiddle.net/t2sYX/2/), feel free to ask help if you're having trouble implementing it:

```
var interval; // Declare a variable to hold the timer OUTSIDE the function, 
              //  so that all event listeners can work with ONE interval
function fade(elem, speed, mode) {
    var count = 0;
    var fade = 1.0;
    clearInterval(interval); // Clear interval, to prevent having multiple
                             //  running intervals
    if (mode === true && count == 0) {
        count = 1;
        interval = setInterval(function() {
            fade = fade - .1;
            if(fade > -.1) document.getElementById(elem).style.opacity = fade;
        }, speed)
    } else {
        count = 0;
        interval = setInterval(function() {
            fade = fade + .1;
            // Updated code below: Replaced < with <=
            if(fade <= 1.1) document.getElementById(elem).style.opacity = fade;
        }, speed)
    }
}
```

Additional tips:

- Store `document.getElementById(elem)` in a variable, outside the interval function (but inside `function fade`, for performace reasons. A varibale look-up is less expensive than a function call.

Comment: Huh. My edit disappeared. Anyway, you should also clear the interval in the `if (fade ... )` block, to prevent the fader from continuing when it's unnecessary.

Comment: Do you have  skype or an email

Comment: The Stack Exchange also provides a chat channel through http://chat.stackoverflow.com/. If you want to have an extended discussion, start a chat, and invite me. I will reserve up to 10 minutes for you.

Comment: @JamesFair At the bottom of the chat page. I have just created a room, join me at: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6117/rob-w-and-james-fair

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6118/discussion-between-james-fair-and-rob-w)

Answer (score 0):

To start with, you never ever stop your interval timer.  Once it starts, it goes forever.  You need to save the return value from setting your interval and stop the timer with clearInterval when you're done with the fade.